# How to override a Laravel package function

Tags: laravel, package

I'm using https://github.com/artesaos/seotools package for seo. 
I am trying to override getCanonical function located at https://github.com/artesaos/seotools/blob/master/src/SEOTools/SEOMeta.php and make it's output as lowercase. Could you please guide me how can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following :

**Step 1:**

Create a child class extending SEOMeta class and override the `getCanonical` function.

```
Class XyzSEOMeta extends SEOMeta {
    public function getCanonical () {
       // Write your logic here
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Create the Service Provider for overridden class. First parameter of `bind` function must be same as facade accessor of `SEOMeta` Facade ([check here](https://github.com/artesaos/seotools/blob/master/src/SEOTools/Facades/SEOMeta.php)). Register this facade in `config/app.php` after the service provider of **seotools** package. :

```
Class XyzSEOMetaServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function register(){
        $this->app->bind('seotools.metatags', function(){
           return new XyzSEOMeta($this->app['config']);
        })
    }
}
```

You are all set. Hope this will help.

**EDIT:**

Above mention method will just override the single class. If you want to change the logic of more than one class. Best way is to fork the project. Change the code and push it to your fork. Use forked project as your composer dependency. Follow the link to know how to use private repository as composer dependency : https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have explained the approach pretty nice. 
I follow this approach and still couldn't achieve my purpose, looks like it's bit more complicated

Comment: **getCanonical** method have been called in the same class with in **generate** function line 128. I copy past and override that as well still no luck.
looking deeper I found out **generate** function have been called within below class line 123:
https://github.com/artesaos/seotools/blob/master/src/SEOTools/SEOTools.php
Could you please explain further, the way that I'm going I might end up override the whole package...

Comment: I'm using the package in my view as follow:
``{!! SEO::generate() !!}``
and I have seotool.php under config, set up as follow:
``'canonical'    => null, // Set null for using Url::current()``

Comment: If thats the case, best option is to create a fork of the project. And use the forked project in your composer.

Comment: @PankitGami.Thanks it works as expected for me .But can you explain how it override methods when we bind contract class. thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple just like we overriding any parent class function in derived class.

Create your own class and extend your package class `SEOMeta` and re-declare function that you want to override and put your logic inside. Don't forget to use namespace of your package class `SEOMeta` at upper your custom class.

Now use your custom class instead of package class inside your controller.

e.g

```
use Path\to\SEOMeta;

class urclassname extends SEOMeta{

    public function overridemethodname(){

        // put ur logic here.
    }

}
```

Comment: Dude. This is not any normal class. It is the Facade of laravel.