# Separate invalid token responses

Tags: laravel, reset-password

Currently, if user tries to reset password using link which was built using reset token, at certain point `validateReset` function inside `PasswordBroker.php` is called. In the body of this function, validation of token itself is done, and if it is not valid `static::INVALID_TOKEN` will be returned. The problem is that from this response I can not know if the token was invalid because token string was wrong or because the token has expired.

My question is if it is possible to override this function to act differently for this two cases, specifically, I want to display informing message to user if token has expired and send him an email containing new reset link.

Comment: What if you [override the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43422719/how-to-override-a-laravel-package-function) and create 2 different exceptions for your case

Comment: Let me check that, thanks for sharing